# Controls within .ascx are not displaying their new value on postback

Tags: asp.net

This seems like an elementary issue but it has me stumped.

I have a main page which loads a custom control (.ascx) on page_load.

This custom control has two fields. One of them being a dropdownlist and the other being a text box. When the dropdownlist changes value it triggers a post back, some logic is executed server side and a value is generated for the textbox. I stepped through the code and the value is created and assigned correctly. However, when the page is rendered the value does not change.

If I change the textbox value to "QQQ" and trigger the postback, "QQQ" stays in the textbox so I can verify viewstate is working.

Is there any reason why the generated value is not being displayed in the form on postback. This process works fine on the initial page load.

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/TRC_BITS.ascx";
   TRC_BITS control = Page.LoadControl(ascxPath) as TRC_BITS;
   phForm.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

**.ascx**

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="message" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" /><br/>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="year" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
      <asp:ListItem Text="2011">2011</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="2012">2012</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="2013">2013</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
```

**.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        year.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    }
    if (year.SelectedValue == 2012)
       message.Text = "ABC";
    else
       message.Text = "XYZ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are adding the controls dynamically, you need to add them during the page's oninit event.
Try it, believe me. Go for it. Yalla.

Comment: That's not a full answer. Depending on the implementation it may or may not work.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're adding these controls to the page dynamically, you need to assign an ID to the user control. Make sure to assign the same ID to the controls every time the page is posted back, and the fields will be repopulated from ViewState.

Also, as Shai suggested, it would be more appropriate if you loaded the controls during `OnInit` instead of `Page_Load`. The situation is a little different with user controls, but in general you want to add your dynamic content before the `LoadViewState` method is executed.

[image]

If you're looking for something to take the pain out of persisting dynamic content, I would suggest taking a look at the [DynamicControlsPlaceHolder](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx).

Comment: @ShaiCohen: Yes, but that generated ID can and will change when more controls are added to the form, which would cause the logic to break.